# Can a file be marked as excluded from future commits?

Tags: git

I have a template file which I've added to my git repository. I'm now making changes to the file for testing but these changes should remain in my working tree and never committed.

I tried adding the file to the exclude list but this has no effect; changes are still visible during an attempt to commit and I have to ignore the file manually every time.

I understand that this is because the file has a history and excluding it would be ambiguous: should it be excluded from reverting to earlier in history, etc.

My question is whether there is a way to mark a file so that I don't accidentally commit it and push it out to a remote repository like github when it's only meant for local testing.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether there is a way to mark a file so that I don't accidentally commit it and push it out to a remote repository like github when it's only meant for local testing.

There is no way to prevent yourself from saying `add myFile` except to use your brain and not say it.

If the question is how to prevent `add .` from including `myFile`, the answer is, put `myFile` in the `gitignore` list *and* `git rm --cached myFile` to get it out of the index.

Answer (score 0):

As [Matt suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065174/3411556) you can add the file to your `gitignore` so the changes to won't be tracked. But I'm assuming you do want to keep to file in your repository after your tests. So you'd have to remove the file from `gitignore` after you're done testing.

So you'd have to either remember not to accidentally commit the change to the file, or remember to remove it from `gitignore`.

Comment: *Just* listing it in `.gitignore` won't help, because the file is tracked. Removing it from Git's index will make it untracked, but that means the file will be omitted from future commits, which means that comparing old commits to new ones will show the file as *deleted*, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Git does have two flag bits you can set in the index.  Neither one is *meant* for what you are doing, but both *work* for what you are doing, provided you remember various caveats.

The two flags are "assume unchanged" and "skip worktree".  The former is meant for systems on which `lstat` system calls are very slow, and the latter is meant for sparse checkout.  If you use either of these intended-uses, the attempt to set the bit for an unintended use could interfere with that.

To set the bits, use `git update-index`.  To remove the setting of the bits, use `git update-index`.  The flags to `git update-index` are:

- `--assume-unchanged`, `--no-assume-unchanged`: sets or clears the assume-unchanged bit
- `--skip-worktree`, `--no-skip-worktree`: sets or clears the skip-worktree bit

You must also provide the names of the index entries on which you wish to set or clear these bits.

Once either bit is set, Git stops actually checking the working tree copy, so that `git add -u`, `git add .`, and the like don't actually add the file: the copy that's already in the index, remains in the index, unchanged.  In fact, `git add` with the file explicitly named usually doesn't update the file in the index either.

It's probably better not to set the flag, and just manually `git restore --source=HEAD --staged myFile` before committing, if you've accidentally staged an updated version.  Note that you can abbreviate this to `git restore --staged myFile` or `git restore -S myFile`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a separate branch for testing:

git checkout -b test_branch_name